# Get wwwroot folder path from ASP.NET 5 controller VS 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Sorry for a noob question, but it seems I can't get Server.MapPath from Controller. I need to output json file list from images folder at wwwroot. They are is at wwwroot/images. How can I get a reliable wwwroot path?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using www.Classes;
using System.Web;

namespace www.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            FolderScanner scanner = new FolderScanner(Server.MapPath("/"));
            return scanner.scan();
        }
    }
}
```

Server.MapPath seems not available from System.Web namespace.

Project is using ASP.NET 5 and dotNET 4.6 Framework

Comment: please update the version of which .Net framework you are using.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You will need to inject `IWebHostEnvironment` into your class to have access to the `ApplicationBasePath` property value: Read about [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1). After successfully injecting the dependency, the **wwwroot path** should be available to you. For example:

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _appEnvironment;

public ProductsController(IWebHostEnvironment appEnvironment)
{
   _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IEnumerable<string> Get()
 {
    FolderScanner scanner = new FolderScanner(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath);
    return scanner.scan();
 }
```

**Edit:** `IHostingEnvironment` has been replaced by `IWebHostEnvironment` in later versions of asp.net.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) www.DNX 4.5.1 D:\Innoware\Projects\VS\Projects\www\src\www\Controllers\ProductsController.cs 4

Comment: Not sure. I am started this solution using the default on VS2015. Single Page Application, Framework 4.6. I haven't modified a single thing

Answer (score 24):

I know this has already been answered, but it has given me different results depending on my hosting environment (IIS Express vs IIS). The following approach seems to work for all hosting environments nicely if you want to get your wwwroot path ([see this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2708)).

**For example**

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

public ProductsController(IHostingEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
   _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
}

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
   FolderScanner scanner = new FolderScanner(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath);
   return scanner.scan();
}
```

Comment: I saw the same issues as the commenter, where the previous answer was giving different results based on IIS Express and IIS.  This one worked consistently!

Comment: As of .Net Core 1.0 this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

For those who deploy to Azure and come into this error. What I did was a work around for it, I haven't tried to figure out why environment of Azure is different than local IIS.
Here is my work around:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_environment.WebRootPath))
{
   _environment.WebRootPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
}
```

Of course you will need:

```
private IHostingEnvironment _environment;

public OnboardingController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
     _environment = environment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is certainly good, but isn't it easier to use the command:

```
string path= Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/wwwroot";
```

learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-7.0

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to implement this right from startup. It is not exact solution to this case per se, but I modified it to suit my need. We need a singleton for this. This is a startup class with environment injection.

```
namespace www
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _env;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
            Environment.rootPath = env.WebRootPath;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

The environment variables I was looking for is there, IHOstingEnvironment. But for my purpose, I need to make Environment class like this to easily access all environment items from all project. This singleton will provide data to configuration, environment, and many other thing. But for this thread, I would just put one `rootPath` property.

```
namespace www.Utilities
{
    public class Environment
    {
        private static Environment instance;
        private static String _rootPath;

        private Environment() { }

        public static Environment Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Environment();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public static string rootPath
        {
            set
            {
                _rootPath = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _rootPath;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

As I have accepted Oluwafemi's answers, I'll keep it that way, since he led me to this. But I think this is the better way to access environment variables throughout the project

Comment: I don't like it. I don't like static singletons. It's against IoC principles.

Comment: IoC specifies for dependencies. I refer to values and constants such as configuration and such.