# Getting a json file in asp5 dnx project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dnx

I would like to use properties from a json file

```
[
 {
    "Name:"Foo",
    "AnotherName":"Bar"
 }
]
```

Which is located in my App_Data folder on the root

In the class I just want to return that file

```
public class FooRepo{

    internal List<FooList> Get(){
       var filePath = ????
    }
}
```

I have tried

`Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/foo.json");` , `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/foo.json"")` ,
`System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;`

I cant seem to figure out how to get this file to use it. Here are the docs on the subject matter https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/file-system.html

> We are currently working on this topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198371/get-wwwroot-folder-path-from-asp-net-5-controller-vs-2015/32198498#32198498

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to use configuration data from a json file in your ASP.NET5 application is to create a static property of type `IConfIigurationRoot` in your `Startup.cs` class, for example

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration
```

Add the following code to the constructor of the Startup class

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Obviously you have to change the value passed to the `SetBasePath` method to make sure that your application can find the json file.

You can access the configuration data from your class through the static property

```
 private Startup _st;
 public FooRepo(Startup st)
 {
     _st = st;
 }

 var emailAddress = _st.Configuration["AppSettings:EmailAddress"];
```

Here is the layout of my json file

**Note:** My json file is called config.json and was added to the root folder of my project.

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "EmailAddress": "info@somedomain.com"
     },
}
```

Comment: This cannot be the way in which to do this . What if you have 2 json files you want to access in different parts of the application? I dont understand how there is zero documentation on this. Is this not a common use case? i kinda feel like accessing a file in the file system is a pretty common thing

Comment: Note that this is the suggested way to replace the AppSettings section in your web.config file (So for configuration of your application only). You can add an additional json file by calling the AddJson file method again. Obviously you can also create multiple builders. This method was suggested by Shaun Wildermuth on Pluralsight, he is a 13 times Microsoft MVP and a ASP.NET insider so this should be the way at the moment

Comment: can you provide a link?

Comment: Do you have a Pluralsight subscription? It is under the MVC6 section, Here is the link, https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnet-5-ef7-bootstrap-angular-web-app/table-of-contents