# How read files from within MockRepository.cs - appEnvironment does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have Visual Studio 2017.  I'm trying to read my csv file into my database to initialize it.  I'm following the training at [pluralsight aspdotnet-core-2-0-mvc-application-visual-studio-2017](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=aspdotnet-core-2-0-mvc-application-visual-studio-2017&author=gill-cleeren&name=add6c574-7e46-41ff-a299-1ab6566238a8&clip=3&mode=live) revising Bethany's Pie Shop for my Node Repo and I'm about halfway through Creating the List Page, Demo Creating the Domain in the training. In the training, they are initializing their DB with static List info, and I want to use my csv file.  But I'm having trouble reading the file.  I looked at [mapPath does not exist in current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195663/server-mappath-does-not-exist-in-current-context), but it didn't fix it for me. So I'm trying the suggestion at [rootFolderPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198371/get-wwwroot-folder-path-from-asp-net-5-controller-vs-2015), then will add the path to my csv file after that.  I'm very new to MVC Web Pages, etc, so I'm having trouble understanding how to apply that last example to my code.

I'm a little confused how appEnvironment will give me rootPath to use with my file that I'm going to use with StreamReader.

Right now I'm seeing

> appEnvironment does not exist in the current context, where I'm trying to return it in my Get().

I know I'm supposed to be returning the IEnumerable there, but how do I get my rootPath? The example that used appenvironment were returning this:

```
FolderScanner scanner = new FolderScanner(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath);
return scanner.scan();
```

I don't have a FolderScanner.  Maybe that's a Microsoft thing? I'm more of a C++/php programmer so I'm not always sure.  Bear with me, I'm trying to learn this brave new (to me) world of Microsoft tech.  This is what I have so far, and I apologize for including a lot of info in my MockNodeRepository.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingEnvironment;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace CATV_Dashboard_Node_Viewer.Models
{
    public class MockNodeRepository : INodeRepository
    {
        private List<Node> _nodes;
        private string csvFile;
        //private string csvFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Data.csv");//System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~htm/external/Data.csv")); //need to check path here

        private string rootPath;
        public string CsvFile { get => csvFile; set => csvFile = rootPath + "/App_Data/Data.csv"; }

        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return appEnvironment.ApplicationName; //appEnvironment doesn't exist in current contest
        }

        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;

        public MockNodeRepository(IHostingEnvironment appEnvironment)
        {
            _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
        }
        public MockNodeRepository()
        {
            if(_nodes == null)
            {
                InitializeNodes();
            }
        }
        private void InitializeNodes()
        {
            _nodes = ConvertCSVtoList(CsvFile);
        }

        private  List<Node> ConvertCSVtoList(string strFilePath)
        {
            List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath);
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(','); //remove header from Stream
            //get each row of csv and convert to node add to List
            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                nodes.Add( new Node { NodeID = rows[0], Color = rows[1], CMTSName = rows[3], PercentDown = Convert.ToInt32(rows[4]), Count = Convert.ToInt32(rows[5]) });
            }
            return nodes;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Node> GetAllNodes()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Node GetNodeByID(string nodeId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your tests should live in a separate project from your web app. When you execute the tests, the harness runs as a standalone console app. The file should reside as content of the test project, and you can get the current directory of the executing test with something like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I don't have tests.

Comment: MockRepository is an interesting name. You can still use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and get the same results. Just get the base directory your app is running (asp.net core is just a console app) and append the folder location to your reference file.

Answer (score 1):

I keep a little statehelper.cs around to store my environment.
I catch and store the environment in startup.cs.
Then I use streamreader as below to write files.  Should work same.

**startup.cs - store ihostingenvironment**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Utilities.StateHelper.HostingEnvironment = env;
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

**StateHelper.cs**

```
public static class StateHelper
{
    public static IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; set; } = null;
}
```

**Use streamreader to write a file - in a controller in Post action handler**

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(formFile.FileName);
filePath = Path.Combine(Utilities.StateHelper.HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "content", fileName );

using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

Happy coding...